Applying Chebychev's inequality in a problem involving 3n i.i.d. random variables
I'm having trouble understanding the use of Chebyshev's inequality in the following.
If $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ are i.i.d. RVs, $\mathbb{E}(Y_1) = \mu$, variance is $\sigma^2$, $X_k = Y_k + Y_{k+1} + Y_{k+2}, S_n = \Sigma_{i = 1}^n X_i$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n - 3\mu n}{\sigma\sqrt{3n}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{n}}\Sigma_{i = 1}^n \frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma} - \frac{2Y_1 + Y_2 - 2Y_{n + 1} - Y_{n + 2}}{\sigma\sqrt{3}n}$, but why does $\frac{2Y_1 + Y_2 - 2Y_{n + 1} - Y_{n + 2}}{\sigma\sqrt{3}n}$ converge in probability to 0?
$\mathbb{E}(2Y_1 + Y_2 - 2Y_{n + 1} - Y_{n + 2}) = 0$, so using Chebyshev's inequality, $P(|2Y_1 + Y_2 - 2Y_{n + 1} - Y_{n + 2}| \geq \sigma\sqrt{3}n) \leq \frac{1}{3n^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so doesn't that just say the fraction is at most 1?

The definition of convergence in Probability (in your case) is: For every $\epsilon>0$ applies: $$P\left(\left|\frac{2Y_1+Y_2-2Y_{n+1}-Y_{n+2}}{\sigma\sqrt3n}-0\right|>\epsilon\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.$$ With your calculation above, you get:
\begin{align*}
P\left(\left|\frac{2Y_1+Y_2-2Y_{n+1}-Y_{n+2}}{\sigma\sqrt3n}\right|>\epsilon\right)&=P\left(\left|{2Y_1+Y_2-2Y_{n+1}-Y_{n+2}}\right|>\epsilon\sqrt3n\sigma\right)\\
&\leq \frac{10}{3n^2\epsilon^2}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.
\end{align*}
So you have convergence in probability.

Sorry for the typo, the SD of $2Y_1+Y_2-2Y_{n+1}-Y_{n+2}$ is of course $\sqrt{10}\sigma$.
